# My UIViewController "does not conform to protocol: 'UITableViewDataSource'"

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

So, first of all, I realize that there are *many* questions like this, and I've gone through at least 13 (I've been counting), but my error never seems to go away. I have some code in Swift for a UITableView that should list what is in an array. Sadly, I get the error that I wrote in the title: ... "does not conform to protocol: 'UITableViewDataSource'". Here is my code. Any idea why it doesn't work?

```
import UIKit

class history: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!
    var items: [String] = ["One", "two", "three", "four", "five"]

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberofRowsInSection section: Int)->Int{
        return items.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)->UITableViewCell {
        let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "acell")
        cell.textLabel!.text = items[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
    }


}
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You have a typo: in `numberofRowsInSection`, you need to capitalize the `Of`.

Comment: I <3 autocomplete (prevents typos).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues with this function:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberofRowsInSection section: Int)->Int{
                                     ^        ^
                            get rid of        Of, not of
```

Comment: That fixed the error, but the "items" are not being added to the table view. Do you know why?

Comment: try `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("acell") as! UITableViewCell`.  Make sure you set the reuse identifier for the prototype cell in Interface Builder to "acell".